# Unity camera background colour

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGh8m.png)In my Unity project  whenever I add a new scene the main camera comes with a background colour. And when I try to view my game in play mode, I observe the background colour of the camera interfering with the real colours of the scene. I want to have a totally transparent camera which is supposed to render only the original scene colours. But I couldn't find any way to prevent this situation. I tried using in "Depth Only" and "Don't Clear" modes but this time only a black scene was observed. Any suggestions regarding this problem please?

Comment: You can't have a totally transparent game image. Something has to be there, and the render buffer is automatically cleared (set to black) before any code you control runs.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You should provide a screenshot that demonstrates the issue you are having. Also a screenshot of the camera settings.